# Javascript random number and background change from button

Tags: javascript, button, random, numbers

I am having trouble. I am looking to press a button and have a random number return into a text box. If the number is even I want to change the background color to Red, and if its odd I want to change the background color to black. I have it almost working,but it does not continue to change the background color when I keep pressing the button, it only does the first. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function BackgroundEven(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#DA0505";
}
function BackgroundOdd(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#000000";
}

function Random() {

return Math.floor(Math.random()*37);
}

var rando= Random();
function Change(){
if(rando%2 == 0)
{
BackgroundEven();
} 
else{
BackgroundOdd();
}
}
}

</script>

<input type="text" name="Result" value="" id="Random" size="5"/>
<input type="button" value="Spin" onclick="document.getElementById('Random').value=Random();Change();" />
</input>
```

Comment: wrap up your onclick into a function (much easier to read). but the issue is that the _var rando_ is only set once when the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating one random number in the `onclick`, then using a newly generated random number for the odd/even check. You need to ensure you're checking against the random number that was stuffed into the input:

```
<input type="button" value="Spin" onclick="Change(document.getElementById('Random').value=Random());" />

function Change(currentNum) {
  if(currentNum % 2 == 0)
    BackgroundEven();
  else
    BackgroundOdd();
}
```

Notice how I pass the newly assigned random number to the `Change()` function so it is operating on the same random number as was stuffed into the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Math.floor(Math.random()*2);`, for 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the random number into Change as an argument instead of relying on closure.

```
function Change(rando){
  if(rando%2 == 0) {
    BackgroundEven();
  } 
  else {
    BackgroundOdd();
  }
}
```

It's also not very pretty to call two or three functions at a time with onclick. Nowadays we would usually append a listener to the object as soon as the document has loaded. That said, to make your code a bit prettier...

```
function clickForRandom(){
  var rando = Random();
  document.getElementById('Random').value = rando;
  Change(rando)
}

<input type="button" value="Spin" onclick="clickForRandom()" />
```